# I'd like to raise detached garage ceiling. What type of roof structure do I have?

Tags: roof

Situation: I have a 2.5 car detached garage with a hip roof and 9' ceiling. I'd like to raise the ceiling as much as reasonably possible in order to fit a full lift in it. It *looks* like these are rafter ties, but they don't look close enough to the rafters to actually be nailed to them. I didn't feel like crawling through all the dirt and insulation to get actual pictures of the connection points.

Can anyone tell me what I'm looking at, exactly?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Notes: I'm not asking for someone to tell me how to raise it (as in, not asking for structural engineering), but I'd like to gather enough information to determine if this is worth looking into (financially speaking) and to not sound like a complete idiot when describing my situation and goals to a structural engineer over the phone.

I know that 9 feet is at least semi-decent and I could fit a maxjack, but I'd prefer a full traditional 2 post lift to fit trucks/suvs as well. Having to center the lift in the building isn't a big deal as I'd want to center it at a 45 degree angle, anyway, to maximize space around the vehicle.

Comment: you can very easily send the pictures to the structural engineer

Comment: A note about 2-post lifts: when figuring how much height you'll get between your floor and the underside of your vehicle, account for the distance between the lifting arms at rest and the lifting points on the vehicle. Unibody SUVs are lifted from hard points on the body that are pretty close to the floor, but pickups or body-on-frame SUVs are lifted from the frame, and those lifting points can be more than a foot off the ground. Even with lift extensions, you lose lifting height. Top of my lift is 4 inches from my 15' ceiling, and I still have to watch where I walk or hit my head.

Comment: @MTA thank you for the reminder that there's never enough room, lol. I'm not vertically gifted, though, so I've been figuring on 6 feet of "body" space plus 5-6 feet for work. I know that's on the liberal end of "enough", but trucks will not be the primary target here - it's mostly for project cars. I just want the ability to do trucks for the occasions I find the need

Answer (score 1):

It's a hip roof. You already answered your own question.

Without that central post (or those central posts if there's more than one), a massive part of your roof load would go diagonally down through the hip rafters to the corners of your garage. Rather than sizing the ridge beam, hip rafters, and elements at the corners of your garage to handle all of that load, the designer put a beam across your walls to take some of the load from the ridge beam and transfer that load through bending to the side walls of your garage.

Comment: So is this design typical of hip roofs? I guess my question was not what I intended to ask, but I'm primarily just trying to figure out if this can *possibly* be raised at least 2-3' for minimal cost/effort (as in, not redesigning the entire structure). I am just trying to avoid consulting an engineer if the resulting design is likely to be 20-30k - structural engineers are hard enough to get a hold of without wasting their time XD.

Comment: @iDriveSidewayz, it's not an unusual design. Can you access enough space with that beam and post left as-is? Were it not for that beam I would be uneasy about removing the ceiling, where I would suspect that the ceiling could be fighting non-trivial outward thrust from the rafters. That beam and post put my mind at ease, though. My expectation is that you can delete the ceiling framing. That would remove lateral bracing that could be important to the beam's stability, but fattening the beam until it's close to square if not actually square probably solves any stability issue.

Comment: @iDriveSidewayz, dropping a post or posts to the floor from the ridge is another cheap option, although I would worry about a car crashing into such post; bollards would probably be involved, too. The classy fix could involve beefing up the ridge beam, hip rafters, top plate splice connections, and corner studs, where then you could remove the beam and the ceiling. That classy option probably comes with a non-trivial engineering bill in comparison to the other options.

Comment: I agree with this answer's description, though a critical point is that it's a _hand-framed_ hip roof. That's a very different animal than a modern engineered truss hip roof. Also, that beam is primarily to support the _ceiling_. The ridge doesn't need support beyond what the rafters provide if you install rafter ties at your new ceiling height. That said, it's not a simple prospect to raise the ceiling with it in place. You need an engineer.

Comment: @isherwood, that beam is primarily to support the ceiling? So they just had that extra post laying around the job and didn't want to pay dumping fees? And their disposal method just happened to coincide with a common structural detail?

Comment: @isherwood, rafter ties act in tension, so moving them upward effectively moves a point load from the end of a rafter toward its middle. Hanging a ceiling from these tension members also adds to this moving point load. How do you know that there's excess capacity in the rafters to apply this load 3 ft higher, which corresponds to about the third point of the rafters?

Comment: @isherwood, I suppose that post could be using the roof to hold up the ceiling.

Comment: Old-timers used ridge board posts because they didn't have engineers designing things for them. New-timers put them in because old-timers did. There are many things like that. Are you proposing that a single 2x4 post (maybe double in an L)  keeps the entire roof from spreading at the walls and sagging? That's an impressive post. Here's the thing: This question is vague and lacking in detail. So is my suggestion, and that's why I haven't posted an answer. I won't be sinking into this pedantic quagmire with you. Good day.

Comment: @iDriveSidewayz, an engineer isn't going to look at your structure and assume that some new-timers have installed a bunch of unnecessary stuff and rearrange things based on that assumption. Doing a full structural analysis for changes that significantly alter load paths (like rafter ties that introduce bending in the rafters or removing that center post) is going to cost bigger money (upwards of 1000 USD). If the engineer is comfortable calling the current design sound, then he can alter things more cheaply by minimizing the disruption to the current system.

Comment: While I may disagree with @isherwood's aggressive approach, pointing out that it's hand framed vs engineered truss is helpful to me. Without a background in this, about the only thing I can do is ask the internet after I've hit a point in my research where I don't think further research will do anything but confuse me. I'm perfectly fine with paying a structural engineer for work and had planned on that exact thing. However, I wanted to gather additional information prior to doing so to determine if it's feasible rather than potentially wasting their time.